# How to change the default C++ template file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, file-templates

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, and whenever I create a new C++ project it gives me a default file with the following code:

```
// Template Test.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}

// Run program: Ctrl + F5 or Debug > Start Without Debugging menu
// Debug program: F5 or Debug > Start Debugging menu

// Tips for Getting Started: 
//   1. Use the Solution Explorer window to add/manage files
//   2. Use the Team Explorer window to connect to source control
//   3. Use the Output window to see build output and other messages
//   4. Use the Error List window to view errors
//   5. Go to Project > Add New Item to create new code files, or Project > Add Existing Item to add existing code files to the project
//   6. In the future, to open this project again, go to File > Open > Project and select the .sln file
```

This is so much unnecessary information and it takes a minute to change it to what I really want;

```
// Template Test.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

It doesn't take very much time, but I have to do it every time I create a new C++ console project in VS 19.

After doing a quick search on my computer I found a folder called 'Templates' at the following location:

> C:\Users\yale\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates

This file has subdirectories that would lead me to think it's the right place, but none of the folders have any template files as I can see.

How can I modify the template files for different projects in C++ with Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: You really should avoid using `using namespace std;` and stick to using `std::name_of thing` or least use `using std::name_of_thing;` and then just having `name_of_thing`.  You can also create a empty project since everything expect `#include <iostream> int main() {}` is not needed.

Comment: Visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-update-existing-templates?view=vs-2019) page may help you.

Comment: I would recommend setting up a lightweight Cmake project baseline, it'll get you used to cmake, and allow you to copy the baseline for each new project you want to develop.

Comment: @LionKing Thanks, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can choose any of them.

**Use the Export Template Wizard:**

Visual Studio provides an Export Template Wizard that can be used to update an existing template:

- Choose File > New > Project from the menu bar.
- Select the template that you want to update and continue through the
  steps to create the new project.
- Modify the project in Visual Studio. For example, change the output
  type or add a new file to the project.
- On the Project menu, choose Export Template.
     The Export Template Wizard opens.
- Follow the prompts in the wizard to export the template as a .zip
  file.
- (Optional) Place the .zip file in the following directory:
  %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio
  \Templates\ProjectTemplates to make it available for
  selection. You'll need to perform this step if you did not select the
  option Automatically import the template into Visual Studio in the
  Export Template Wizard.
- Delete the old template .zip file.

**To manually update an existing template:**

- Locate the .zip file that contains the template. User project
  templates are located at %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio
  \Templates\ProjectTemplates.
- Extract the .zip file.
- Modify or delete the current template files, or add new files to the
  template.
- Open, modify, and save the .vstemplate XML file to handle updated
  behavior or new files.
- Select the files in your template, and from the right-click or
  context menu, and choose Send to > Compressed (zipped) folder. The
  files that you selected are compressed into a .zip file.
- Put the new .zip file in the same directory as the old .zip file.
- Delete the extracted template files and the old template .zip file.

Also, you can visit the [source page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-update-existing-templates?view=vs-2019) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much!.  I was searching for how to make visual studio to keep using C++ language standard of ISO C++20 in visual studio community edition 2022. didn't thought making visual studio templet and configuring it to c++ 20 and export it as templet and then use it as starter template it could work. Thank you very much. :))