# How to change the default language standard for all projects in Visual Studio. C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am still learning the language, and I cannot seem to find an easy explanation here or otherwise how to change the default language standard in Visual Studio for all projects.

Is there an easy way to change the C++ Language Standard so that when creating new projects, it defaults to that standard? I would think that there would be a simple menu option in Visual Studio that would allow this without needing to go into the properties for every individual project.

Comment: I believe there's a way to create templates, similar to like "console project" etc, that you could control this in, something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default C++ language standard in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084421/how-to-change-default-c-language-standard-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: It seems the template works and saves the properties as I was looking for. Thank you!!! Also, I had looked over that question as it matches mine but does not provide the answer I was looking for, it is a bit overly complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe there's a way to create templates, similar to like "console project" etc, that you could control this in, something like [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019) – Tas